# Electron require module error for externally installed node modules in renderer process

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, electron

I am working on electron app, where I load external web app which is developed in angular into electron.
Everything is working fine.

But I want to read file info, for that I need **"mime"** module and I got it from here.

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime](http://Mime)

I have installed it, using node js command prompt, using commands **"npm install mime"** with different attributes like -g, --save-dev, etc. and it installed correctly.

Real headache is starts from here :(

Whenever I tried to create instance of mime using following code

> var mime = require("mime");

It shows an error  :(

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'mime'
```

This happens for every externally installed module using npm.

But below code snippet is working fine

```
var events = require('events');
```

This code is resides in a javascript file which is loaded through web app.

Comment: Are you using a build system like webpack or browserify ? Are you in the main process or the renderer process ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, I am not using any build system, only node commands like start, rebuild, etc. Its in renderer process.

Comment: Are you using the `start`command or the `electron` command to run the app?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that in your `package.json`, you have the new dependency:

```
  "homepage": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mime": "^1.0"
  }
}
```

The `--save` should have taken care of that...